# How to run a SEM mediation test with common method bias

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

Say the model I am working with is simply:

```
M <- IV
DV <- IV + M
```

All three constructs are obtained using the same survey, hence the common method bias issue. I thought about allowing the error terms of all three correlate, but then SEM can't compute standard errors.

Is there another way to counter this common method bias using lavaan?

Comment: Questions about lavaan syntax are off topic here and will be closed. I have edited the question, because it is more broad than just lavaan.

Comment: And I think the answer is no.

Comment: Well, I know one way conceptually for SEM to counter this is to add a common latent factor (Podsakoff, MacKenzie, Lee, & Podsakoff, 2003; Williams, Edwards, & Vandenberg 2003). But I am not sure if lavaan can do this... as it is unobserved variable/I have no data for it.

Comment: You can add it, but the model won't be identified.

Comment: ... Unless M, IV and DV are latent and have at least three (?) indicators each. This is true of every SEM program.